# Scraping elements from a Youtube video

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to take some tags from youtube videos like the title, the number of views etc.I use BeautifulSoup for that but I want to make it faster.Here is my code:

```
#for the title
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = re.findall('content=.*>\n\n',urllib2.urlopen(link).read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()

#for the number of views
soup0 = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(link).read())
for items in soup0.findAll('strong'):
    if re.match("^[0-9]*$", str(items).strip("<strong>").rstrip("</strong>")):
        viewcount=str(strongs).strip("<strong>").rstrip("</strong>")
```

Comment: well, is it actually noticeably slow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [google's youtube api](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python.html).

Part of their example:

```
def PrintEntryDetails(entry):
   print 'Video title: %s' % entry.media.title.text
   print 'Video published on: %s ' % entry.published.text
   print 'Video description: %s' % entry.media.description.text
   print 'Video category: %s' % entry.media.category[0].text
   print 'Video tags: %s' % entry.media.keywords.text
   print 'Video watch page: %s' % entry.media.player.url
   print 'Video flash player URL: %s' % entry.GetSwfUrl()
   print 'Video duration: %s' % entry.media.duration.seconds
```

Comment: I tried this way and it worked.If you have a list with youtube links,and you want to just grab some information,is there a restriction or a way to do it fast ?

Comment: Sounds like a separate question ;) Hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768805/gdata-youtube-obtaining-thumbnails/6771468#6771468 and http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/json.html